# Geometric intuition for why $\int_0^\theta \cos xdx = \sin\theta$

Tags: calculus, intuition, trigonometric-integrals

Why is $\int_0^\theta \cos x dx = \sin\theta$? How does the area under the cosine curve from 0 to some angle $\theta$ relate to the unit circle definition of $\sin\theta$, i.e, as the vertical distance travelled across the unit circle circumference from 0 to $\theta$. Is there a way to see how these two geometric pictures relate to each other, so as to develop an intuition for the equality?

Comment: Because of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, this question is equivalent to asking why the derivative of $\sin(\theta)$ is equal to $\cos(\theta)$. You may be interested in the geometric intuition of this question as well. See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4o7sraVMZg

Comment: I haven't learnt about the fundamental theorem of calculus yet.

Comment: By the fundamenta theorem of calculus (which has an easy geometric visualization), that integral equation is equivalent to two things: 1. $$\sin(0) = 0,$$ 2. $$\sin'(t) = \cos(t).$$ 1 is obvious, and 2 stems from the fact that the derivative of $(\cos(t), \sin(t))$ is itself rotated counterclockwise by a quarter turn. This is manifested in $\frac{d}{dt}e^{it} = i e^{it}$.

Comment: I haven't learnt about derivatives yet either, I'm learning integration first. All I really know in calculus is basic integration.

Comment: It is an interesting question although I doubt that something really intuitive can come up with this integral relation. Even worse if you don’t know what the fundamental theorem of calculus is.I hope I’m wrong!

Comment: @MahdiR. How did you arrive at the equation $\int_{0}^{\theta}\cos(t)\,dt = \sin(\theta)$ then?

Comment: @MahdiR. Can you precise what you mean by basic integration ? It is rare to learn integration before introducing the derivative.

Comment: @Mason I tried to find a way to derive a formula for the cosine integral, and noticed that sin($\theta$) matched up perfectly, but I have no idea how. I didn't do anything special, just calculation.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I am learning through Apostol's textbook, he goes through integration first. I know about the basic properties of definite integrals, about how to evaluate some simple functions e.g with fractional powers, that's about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Imagine a particle moving counterclockwise around the unit circle at unit angular velocity. Then at time $t$ the particle is at point $(\cos t, \sin t)$. The velocity vector at that point is $(-\sin t, \cos t)$. The second component, $\cos t$, is the rate at which the $y$ coordinate in increasing.

Now remember that integration is good for more things than finding areas.
The integral of velocity is the distance covered(1): the distance covered is the area under the velocity curve.

In this case the *vertical* distance covered in the time interval $[0, \theta]$ is $\sin \theta$, the $y$ coordinate of the point you reach. So
$$
\int_0^\theta \cos t dt  = \sin \theta.
$$

(1) That sentence is really the essence of the fundamental theorem of calculus. Remember it when you get to that theorem.

Comment: Wow, I've never seen that explanation, that's great.

Comment: So, if you have intuition for the fundamental theorem of calculus you have intuition for this integral?

Comment: Also, sorry, this answer is difficult for me to understand because I haven't done anything with integration in physics, I don't understand where the velocity vector of t is in the unit circle picture.

Comment: Really nice! Not sure though that the OP knows what the velocity vector is and that it is orthogonal to the radius for a point moving counterclockwise around the unit circle at unit angular velocity.

Comment: Nice! This is probably about as simple as it gets.

Comment: The velocity vector is the tangent at the point?

Comment: @MahdiR. When a particle moves in the plane the velocity vector points in the direction the particle is moving at that moment and the length of the vector is the speed. So for uniform motion around the circle the direction of motion at any point is tangent to the circle, so perpendicular to the radius.

Answer (score 0):

We can develop an intuition for the equality noting that the value of $A(\theta)=\int_0^\theta \cos xdx$ corresponds to the area under the graph for $\cos x$ between $0$ and $\theta$ and we have that

- for $\theta =0$ we have $A(0)=0$ and indeed $\sin 0 =0$
- for $\theta \in(0,\pi/2)$ we have that $A(\theta)$ increases and indeed also $\sin \theta$ increases
- for $\theta =\pi/2$ we have $A(\pi/2)$ reaches its maximum and indeed $\sin (\pi/2) =1$ which is its maximum
- $\ldots$

and so on according to the following sketch

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't understand how this picture relates to the vertical movement across the unit circle circumference, though. I want to understand the connection. This is the area under the curve, but I want to know why the area under the curve here is equal to the vertical distance across a unit circle circumference.

Comment: @MahdiR. Maybe this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6JCwzA8xX4) also can help. Let me know.

Comment: Yes, I know how a point moving around the unit circle circumference generates the sine and cosine waves, but I am still unable to understand how the area under the cosine curve relates to the vertical distance in the unit circle.

Comment: The relation for any point is difficult to see in this way but you can appreciate the relation for the key points: 0, $pi/2$, $\pi$, $3\pi/2$, $2\pi$. To go behind this simple analogy, I think that the elegant way Ethan Bolker is the best one to see the relation in general. If you need some more explanation, please do not hesitate. Bye